# Integral result contains one term is infinite large and one term is infinite small.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrate this function from $0$ to $f$.

$
\int_0^f\dfrac{p\cdot\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln\left(r\right)\,x}{\left(r-1\right)t}}-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{r\ln\left(r\right)\,x}{\left(r-1\right)t}}\right)}{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln\left(r\right)}{r-1}}-\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{r\ln\left(r\right)}{r-1}}}dx
$

https://www.integral-calculator.com/

I use this website, and the result is

$
\dfrac{p\cdot\left(r-1\right)t\cdot\left(\left(\left(r-1\right)\mathrm{e}^\frac{f\ln\left(r\right)}{\left(r-1\right)t}-r\right)\mathrm{e}^\frac{fr\ln\left(r\right)}{\left(r-1\right)t}+\mathrm{e}^\frac{f\ln\left(r\right)}{\left(r-1\right)t}\right)\mathrm{e}^\frac{\left(r+1\right)\ln\left(r\right)\left(t-f\right)}{\left(r-1\right)t}}{r\cdot\left(\mathrm{e}^\frac{r\ln\left(r\right)}{r-1}-\mathrm{e}^\frac{\ln\left(r\right)}{r-1}\right)\ln\left(r\right)}
$

I have some number for the parameters, namely
$r=1.5, t=1e-6, p=1e9, f=2e-3$
In the result, $\mathrm{e}^\frac{fr\ln\left(r\right)}{\left(r-1\right)t}$ is infinite, and $\mathrm{e}^\frac{\left(r+1\right)\ln\left(r\right)\left(t-f\right)}{\left(r-1\right)t}$ is
infinitely small.

The original function looks like this (I only plot from $0$ to $2e-5$), it should have an integral which is the area under the curve
[image]

So how to compute the integral.